# analysis of conjunction : A newspaper is only kind of reading that is almost universal

Tags: conjunctions

> A newspaper is the only kind of reading that is almost universal

**How do we understand this sentance in terms of grammar** ?

This has a *meaning* :

- A newspaper is the only kind of reading for almost universal
- There are things that almost people read and it is the only one, newspaper.

Hence in my thought,

- A newspaper is the only kind + almost universal is reading
- A newspaper is the only kind of reaing that almost universal is

Hence please, **why is the order of almost universal and is changed** ?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't omitted _the_ before _only_? The sentence would make sense with that addition.

Comment: Thank you for your correction.

Comment: OK. There are many kinds of reading [matter]. Only one kind is almost universal. A newspaper is that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adverb "almost" is qualifying the word it precedes - "universal" - to mean that it is "*not quite* universal", or "*very nearly* universal".

Without "almost", the sentence would be a very sweeping statement that suggests *everybody* in the whole world reads newspapers - and that is simply not true.

Saying that reading newspapers is *almost* universal allows for the fact that some people do not read newspapers, and maybe a few countries or even cultures are exceptions to that rule. As written, it seems a reasonable statement that reading newspapers is closer to being universal than other kinds of reading.